# storing current path in variable and reusing it

Tags: variables, batch-file, cd

I know similar questions have already been asked, but somehow I am unable to figure out the mistake in my code.
I'm making  a .bat file with the following code

```
echo off 
echo %cd%
set curr_directory = "%cd%"
echo $curr_directory
pause
```

OUTPUT is :

```
C:\Users\MyDesktop>echo off
C:\Users\MyDesktop>
$curr_directory
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So what I dont get is why the value of variable `curr_directory` is not being printed.
What i eventually want to do is use the variable to change the directory something like this: `cd $curr_directory`

Thanks

Comment: you may be interested in `pushd` and `popd`

Comment: Variables in batch are called by using `%variable%` instead of `$variable`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone .. it works!! :D

Comment: By the way, it's better to use `set "curr_directory=%cd%"` than `set curr_directory = "%cd%"`. That way your variable won't contain double quotes but it still works for paths containing spaces.

Comment: Odd that you would use percent symbols for one variable but not the other.  All things being equal the simplest explanation tends to be the right one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where to start. EVERYTHING about your code is wrong. This should work:

```
@echo off 
echo %cd%
set curr_directory=%cd%
echo %curr_directory%
pause
```

In batch you access variables via `%var%` and not `$var`. Further, DO NOT PUT SPACES behind `=`. `SET x=123` will store 123 in x but `SET x= 123` will store _123 (_ means space) in x.

EDIT: As SomethingDark stated, the first line should be `@echo off` except you actually want the message `echo off` to be printed. And yes, `SET x = 123` means `%x %` is `123`

Comment: Well, not _everything_. Speaking of wrong, your first line should be `@echo off`.

Comment: :) OK, you might be right but echo off is not an error if you actually want "echo off" to be printed :)

Comment: `will store _123 (_ means space) in x` - no. it will be stored in `%x %` instead of `%x%`

Comment: ...and the TITLE of the question is also wrong: by "current path" we understand the current value of `PATH` variable, not "current directory"

Answer (score -1):

use %curr_directory% instead of $curr_directory

Avoid spaces inbetween like the below one

"set curr_directory = %cd%"

below should work

```
echo off 
echo %cd%
set curr_directory=%cd%
echo curr_directory is %curr_directory%
pause
```

Comment: Congratulations, you know how to copy and paste the other answer that was here two hours earlier. Literally the only reason I'm not downvoting you is because I don't waste downvotes on users that have 1 rep.